# How to return a command from a c++ application to parent terminal?

Tags: c++, bash, qt, path, environment-variables

Is it possible to run a c++ application from a terminal and on certain conditions return a command back into the terminal from which it was called from? For instance, if I were to run an application within my terminal and after my selections; my application needs to change my PATH by running an export command such as:

*(USING BASH)*

```
export PATH=.:/home/User/application/bin:$PATH
```

After I'm done and before my application completely closes can I make the application change my terminals local environment variables with the above command? Does Qt offer a way of doing this? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: [this](http://www.google.com/search?q=qt+execute+system+commands), basically as standard general approach to the C++ you probably want to use `system()`, QT offers the `QProcess` class as a slightly advanced alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot change parent application environment.

Why? When your parent app started yours (probably using `system()`), it actually `fork()`ed - child process was born as to be almost exact replica of parent, and then that child used `execve()` call, which completely replaced executable image of that process with executable image of your application (for scripts it would be image of interpreter like bash).

In addition to that, that process also prepared few more things. One is list of open files, starting with file handles 0,1,2 (stdin, stdout, stderr). Also, it created memory block (which belongs to child process address space) which contains environment variables (as key=value pairs).

Because environment block belongs to your process, you can change your own environment as you please. But, it is impossible for your process to change environment memory block of parent (or any other process for that matter). The only way to possibly achieve this would be to use IPC (inter-process communication) and gently ask parent to do this task inside of it, but parent must be actively listening (on local or network socket) and be willing to fulfill such request from somebody, and child is not any special compared to any other process in that regard.

This also reason why you can change environment in bash using some shell script, but ONLY using `source` or `.` bash macro - because it is processed by bash itself, without starting any external process.

However, you cannot change environment by executing any other program or script for reasons stated above.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation. I understand that parents can modify children and not the other way around. But for something as underlining as a bash process with an interface capable of accepting commands; cant I just have my applications pass a couple commands back into terminal?

Comment: Sorry, no, you can't. When child returns, all process remnants completely disappear. And the whole act of "returning" is simply parent finally getting control after long `waitpid()` on child's process id

Comment: I don't mean to beat a dead horse here but hear me out. After reviewing http://www.serverhostingsecrets.com/tutorials/execute-shell-command-using-cc/ it would appear that passing commands to the terminal can occur. Let say I tell my application to make a script file with export code to be sourced and then pass a source command to the terminal to source the file created? Do you think that would work..?

Comment: If caller process is actively cooperating - of course you can (if parent reads stdout or saved file from child and then interprets it). But it will not work as generic approach.

Comment: So is there a way to make my parent terminal actively cooperate? Maybe some documentation that explains this process?

Answer (score 1):

The common solution is to have your application print the result to standard output, then have the invoker pass it to its environment. A textbook example is `ssh-agent` which prints an environment variable assigment; you usually invoke it with `eval $(ssh-agent)`

Comment: In other words, parent must be actively cooperating